# @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho o seguinte campo `classificacao` em uma tabela.

Esse campo é preenchido em outro lugar e é preenchido com, somente, `'P'` ou `'N'`, acrônimos para **Positivo** e **Negativo**.

Criei então o `enum` Java.

**Classificacao.java**

```
public enum Classificacao {
    POSITIVO('P'), NEGATIVO('N');

    private char classificacao;

    Classificacao(char classificacao) {
        this.classificacao = classificacao;
    }

    public char getClassificacao() {
        return classificacao;
    }
}
```

Na minha entidade, eu tenho o atributo:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Convert(converter = ClassificacaoEnumConverter.class)
@Column(name = "classificacao", length = 1)
private Classificacao classificacao;
```

Quando tento listar essa tabela, a seguinte exception é lançada:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [N] for enum class [br.com.jpalab.enums.Classificacao]
```

Entendo o porque do erro, ele procura o valor `N`, sendo que só existe `POSTIVO` e `NEGATIVO`, mas como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Criei esse Converter

```
@Converter
public class ClassificacaoEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<Classificacao, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Classificacao classificacao) {
        return String.valueOf(classificacao.getClassificacao());
    }

    @Override
    public Classificacao convertToEntityAttribute(String classificacaoFromDb) {
        if (classificacao == null) return null;
        switch (classificacaoFromDb) {
            case "P":
                return Classificacao.POSITIVO;
            case "N":
                return Classificacao.NEGATIVO;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema está descrito nessa documentação. https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Converter.html (...)"Note that Id attributes, version attributes, relationship attributes, and attributes explicitly annotated as Enumerated or Temporal (or designated as such via XML) will not be converted." (...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar um [**`Converter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html) com um [**`AttributeConverter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html):

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

public enum Classificacao {
    POSITIVO('P'), NEGATIVO('N');

    private final char classificacao;

    Classificacao(char classificacao) {
        this.classificacao = classificacao;
    }

    public char getClassificacao() {
        return classificacao;
    }

    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public static class Mapeador implements AttributeConverter<Classificacao, String> {

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Classificacao x) {
            return String.valueOf(x.getClassificacao());
        }

        @Override
        public Classificacao convertToEntityAttribute(String y) {
            if (y == null) return null;
            if ("P".equals(y)) return POSITIVO;
            if ("N".equals(y)) return NEGATIVO;
            throw new IllegalStateException("Valor inválido: " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.Convert;

// ...

    //@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Convert(converter = Classificacao.Mapeador.class)
    @Column(name = "classificacao", length = 1)
    private Classificacao classificacao;
```

Observe que o `@Enumerated` foi retirado do mapeamento.

Comment: Sem o converter não deveria ser o suficiente? Ao menos para JPA é, iirc.

Comment: @GustavoCinque Daí o `name()` de cada elemento do `enum` teria que ser persistido. Ou seja, ao invés de ser apenas `P` e `N` no banco de dados, teria que ser `POSITIVO` e `NEGATIVO`.

Comment: True, só depois que comentei que percebi que havia diferença no que o autor queria como nome de enum e o que estava indo à banco.

Comment: Já tentei usar Converter, ele continua lançando a **mesma** exception

Comment: Foi mais rápido do que eu :). Alternativamente podemos criar uma tabela `CLASSIFICACAO` com `ID` e `NOME`. Então podemos criar uma FK na tabela que usa a *enum* referenciando `CLASSIFICACAO.CLASSIFICAO_ID`  e mapear com `@Column(name="CLASSIFICAO_ID") 
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`.  A vantagem é que se a *enum* mudar de alguma forma (e.g., se você renomear ou adicionar valores) é bem mais fácil de fazer a mudança, apesar disso criar problemas se você reordenar os membros da *enum* somente do lado do Java.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago Tentou o `@Converter(autoApply = true)`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, inclusive, eu coloquei um log e debuguei, os métodos da interface AtributteConverter não estão nem sendo chamados.

Comment: o `autoapply = true` é pra quando você quiser fazer isso pra todos os atributos que tenha Classificacao, mesmo setando o converter na anotação @Convert, ou seja, sendo redundante, não dá certo

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago Qual é a versão do seu JPA? E do hibernate?

Comment: `<hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>`

Comment: só tenho essa dependência, não tenho dependência do jpa

Comment: retirei a anotação de `@Enumerated` e funcionou.

Comment: --' :( :D --' :( :D

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago KKKKKKK - Ou seja, tem que ser o Converter sem o Enumerated.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago Resposta editada.

Comment: exato, puts! kkkkkkk