# Como definir qual dado de um ENUM o JPA irá persistir no banco?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá, gostaria de saber como anotar uma propriedade (ID) do meu ENUM para quando for persistir no banco?

Pois atualmente o JPA está salvando o index do array do enum e não o ID...
Meu enum:

```
    @Getter
public enum SituacaoEnum {
    ABERTO(1, "Aberto"),
    EMEDICAO(2, "Em edicao"),
    FECHADO(3, "Fechado");

    Integer codigo;
    String marca;

    private Integer valor;

    MarcaBalcaoEnum(Integer valor, String marca) {

        this.valor = valor;
        this.marca = marca;

    }
}
```

Comment: Tem essa também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251747/112052

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a anotação `@Enumerated` que tem duas opções:

`EnumType.STRING` - Lê e grava o valor do `.name()` do seu enum.

`EnumType.ORDINAL`- Lê e grava o valor do `.ordinal()` do seu enum.

Lembrando que as duas opções tem a fragilidade de que se você deletar ou reordenar tipos, poderá ter inconsistência na base.

Se você quer gravar o código começando de 1, pode adicionar como primeiro tipo do seu enum um com código 0 que não será utilizado, porque o método `.ordinal()` sempre inicia do zero.